# How to get Input control value in controller's Index method asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on captcha authentication. I want to get user entered captcha value in controller's Index method. Below is my `cshtml` file code

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
 }
<div class="container">
   <label for="captcha"><b>Enter chaptcha -  </b></label>
   <label id="lblshowCaptcha"><b>@ViewData["captcha"]</b></label>
   <input id="txtCapValue" type="text" placeholder="Enter captcha" name="cap" required>
     <br/>
   <button class="button" type="submit">Login</button>
     <br />
</div>
```

When user entering captcha value in `txtCapValue` **and click submit button** I need that value in controller. Here is my controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    randnumber = RandomString(6);
    ViewData["captcha"] = randnumber;
    return View();
}
```

how can I get `txtCapValue input` control value when user click on `submit` button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get user entered captcha value in controller's Index
> method.

There are two options, you can try:

Option1: use Form Tag Helper

Index method:

```
public IActionResult Index(string cap)
        {
          
            ViewData["captcha"] = 6;//do your staff
            return View();
        }
```

Index view:

```
<form method="get" asp-action="Index">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="captcha"><b>Enter chaptcha -  </b></label>
        <label id="lblshowCaptcha"><b>@ViewData["captcha"]</b></label>
        <input id="txtCapValue" type="text" placeholder="Enter captcha" name="cap" required>
        <br />
        <button class="button" type="submit">Login</button>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

Option 2: use ajax

Index method:

```
 public IActionResult Index(string cap)
        {
          
            ViewData["captcha"] = 6;
            return View();
        }
```

Index view:

```
<div class="container">
    <label for="captcha"><b>Enter chaptcha -  </b></label>
    <label id="lblshowCaptcha"><b>@ViewData["captcha"]</b></label>
    <input id="txtCapValue" type="text" placeholder="Enter captcha" name="cap" required>
    <br />
    <button id="buttonDemo1" class="button" type="submit">Login</button>
    <br />
</div>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#buttonDemo1').click(function () {
                var cap = $("#txtCapValue");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/Home/Index',
                    data:  cap 
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One of the easy ways using the [Form Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-form-tag-helper):

```
<form asp-controller="Controller_Name" asp-action="Captcha" method="post">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="captcha"><b>Enter chaptcha -  </b></label>
        <label id="lblshowCaptcha"><b>@ViewData["captcha"]</b></label>
        <input id="txtCapValue" type="text" placeholder="Enter captcha" name="cap" required>
        <br />
        <button class="button" type="submit">Login</button>
        <br />
    </div>
</form>
```

And on the server side:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Captcha(string cap)
{
    ... using the `cap`

    return View("Index");
}
```